# Windows Form Sizing Not Properly Displayed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form. Previously the form displayed correct size I double check already the properties and everything looks correct.

Size should be 1024 x 768 but for some weird reason the form keeps on extending downwards sharing screenshot:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried changing my laptop's resolution but it doesn't seem to work and besides the target size is only 1024 x 768

Comment: What is the Form's `StartPosition` property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @rfmodulator centerscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug on my code , somewhere I'm resizing it programatically so I just had to remove it

Comment: and you can also add max, min size prop for the form to escape unexpected resizing